# How to create div pagination?

Tags: jquery, image, pagination

I have a lot of divs on my page, which contains images. And I need to show only 12 on one page. I searched the Internet and others recommend JQuery. Can you help me do this?

Structure:
(everything is wrapped in "wrapper div")

[image]

Comment: Do you need to 'hide' when there's more than 12 or not include them in the html at all (so the page loads quicker)?  Sounds like something you should be doing when generating the html (server-side) - otherwise you're not improving the performance of the page.

Answer (score -1):

try to use the slider or carousel
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/carousel/
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/slider/

for example:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/